# Valor dos Inputs de um formulário

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário com javascript/jquery em que de um pergunta para outra vai para outra pagina e na última página eu tenho que vê todos os dados digitados nas questões anteriores, já tentei com o serializearray(),mas ele só pega os dados da última página, gostaria de saber se tem algum outro método ou mesmo com o serializearray.

Comment: apenas com JS??

Comment: cria um imput hidden com o value do serializearray e passa pra proxima pagina

Comment: Sim, tem que ser com javascript, você poderia me mostrar um exemplo?

Comment: Já tentou com localStorage?

Comment: Não, na verdade não sei usar o localstorage, pode me dá um help? algum exemplo ou página que me mostre como usar, dei uma pesquisada mas não entendi direito

Comment: Acredito que a melhor forma para você fazer isso seja com o LocalStorage.
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API_pt_br/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o localStorage como falaram!

Para exemplificar fiz esse [Codepen](https://codepen.io/victorjordan95/pen/gzoQQK) para te ajudar!

Segue dois artigos muito bom para entender como funciona o localStorage:

[Artigo 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage)

[Artigo 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)

Answer (score 1):

Cara vou te dar um exemplo básico aqui e espero que lhe ajude.

**Página que você pega o valor para transferir para outra página:**

```
<input type="text" id="texto">
<a href="mostraDados.html"><button type="button" onclick="setaValor()">Pegar</button></a>

<script>
    function setaValor() {
        var texto = document.getElementById('texto');
        var textoValor = texto.value;
        var textoStorage = window.localStorage.setItem('valorTexto', textoValor);
    }
</script>

<style>
    input { border: solid 1px #ccc; border-radius: 2px; height: 20px; }
    button { border: solid 1px #ccc; border-radius: 2px; height: 30px; cursor: pointer;}
</style>
```

**Página que recebe a váriavel com o valor da página anterior:**

```
<input type="text" id="recebeTexto"> Valor trazido da página anterior 
<br><br>
<a href="setaDados.html"><button type="button">Voltar</button></a>

<script>
    function mostraValor() {
        var textoRecebido = window.localStorage.getItem('valorTexto');      
        document.getElementById('recebeTexto').value = textoRecebido;           
    }   

    window.onload = function() {
        mostraValor();
    };
</script>

<style>
    input { border: solid 1px red; border-radius: 2px; height: 20px; }
    button { border: solid 1px #ccc; border-radius: 2px; height: 30px; cursor: pointer;}
</style>
```